# Cordova IOS =>' Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred'

Tags: ios, cordova, ssl, taco

I am working with visual studio cordova and we embeded an Iframe. On android it is working fine, but on Ios (9+) :

> Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure
>   connection to `the server cannot be made.

I ve read other thread suggesting to change NSAppTransportSecurity. I've done it via [Transport Security Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-transport-security).

```
<dict>

          <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
          <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
              <key>mywebsite.com</key>
              <dict>
                <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
              </dict>
            </dict>
          </dict>
        </dict>
```

I've change the CSP:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
        content="default-src * gap: ;
                   style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                   script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
                    'child-src'*;
                    'frame-src':*;      
        " />
```

I stil got this error. Any help out there?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is coming from the iframe that is embedded.
It is using an sha-1 signature for the certification and Apple doesn't allow this signature. So I am changing the signature.